# Springfox Java Bean Validations not displaying in Swagger Output

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I'm trying to follow the documentation for Springfox Swagger to get Java Bean Validation to work (http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#springfox-support-for-jsr-303), but they are not showing up in the Swagger UI.

**This is my Spring Configuration:**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@EnableSwagger2
@Import({springfox.bean.validators.configuration.BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class})
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket docket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .select()
                .build();
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("My API")
                .build();
    }
}
```

**This is my request mapping:**

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Use to get token for internal applications")
@PostMapping(value = AuthUris.TOKEN)
public AuthResponse token(@Valid @RequestBody AuthRequest authRequest) {
// implementation omitted
}
```

**This is my POJO:**

```
@ApiModel
public class AuthRequest {
    @ApiModelProperty
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String username;
    @NotNull
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

I expected the NotNull and Size annotations to be captured in the Swagger UI but they are not. Please help me understand how this should work.  Thank you.

[image].

So thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/8012379/indra-basak I do see that they were working.  However, I have to hover over the field to thinks like @Size.  See the screenshot below.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- If you are using **springfox** version `2.7.0`, both `@NotNull` and `@Size` annotations should work.
- Your `@NotNull` annotation is already working in the `password field`.
- If `@ApiModelProperty` annotation is present for a field, it takes precedence over `@NotNull` annotation. It is the case with the `username` field. It shows up as `optional` because the `required` attribute of `@ApiModelProperty` annotation is set to `false` by default.

If you use **springfox** version `2.7.0` and don't use `@ApiModelProperty` annotation, the model will show up as:

[image]

#### Validation

For example, if you enter a username less than the minimum size of 4, you will get the following exception:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1511550365198,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException",
  "errors": [
    {
      "codes": [
        "Size.authRequest.username",
        "Size.username",
        "Size.java.lang.String",
        "Size"
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "codes": [
            "authRequest.username",
            "username"
          ],
          "arguments": null,
          "defaultMessage": "username",
          "code": "username"
        },
        50,
        4
      ],
      "defaultMessage": "size must be between 4 and 50",
      "objectName": "authRequest",
      "field": "username",
      "rejectedValue": "s",
      "bindingFailure": false,
      "code": "Size"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Validation failed for object='authRequest'. Error count: 1",
  "path": "/tokens"
}
```

Comment: I see from your post that it was working before.  However I noticed that I have to hover over the field in order to see things like @Size information.  Your screenshot shows it differently though.  I updated my original question to show a screenshot of this. Any thoughts?

Comment: My screenshot was due to `io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.6.1` library. Though I was using the latest `2.7.0` version, my browser was picking up some of the older static files from the `2.6.1` version as I didn't clean my browser cache.

Comment: Ah that makes sense now.  Seems like 2.7.0 shows the information only when you hover over.  Thanks again.